My character legs keeps getting stuck in a location
walking Cube project I'm trying to create a walking creature with 4 legs but any time I try to make it move from a location it always seems it's locked or linked in place. I cleared the location and rotation and applied a new one, but every time I press G to move them, the legs always seems to be locked to the "follow-path" I used to simulate the movement.


Is it possible you've set the legs (or their controllers) to follow the path, when only their parent should be following the path ?

Please share your file

@RobinBetts please can you elaborate more I'm a beginner

It looks as though the legs might have a path constraint? When  the only constraint they should have is being a child of their parent? Just a guess, though.

sorry, but without any technical information what you did, we can just guess around - as you can see in the comments. So please read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question by providing all necessary informations so that we are able to help you. thx for your understanding.

@moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OPGyyC9wO8t1Zrs2MhZR4shwOAnIei55/view?usp=drive_link

your link asks for an authorization ;)

thanks for your concern @moonboots this is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1251_9hpBayL33e3c88hAqd5HVCLNhIc7/view?usp=sharing

Unparent the IK empties from the empty called Empty. These IK empties are submitted to the influences of both this empty and the curve they are following, which makes them drift away as soon as you move Empty:

Result:

